# DateOffset in Pandas with a Holiday Calendar

Tags: pandas

Pandas currently allows you to add business days to a given date `datetime.today() + 3*BDay()`.  I would like to extend the idea of a business day to exclude a given DateIndex of holidays as well as weekends.  Is that possible incorporate a DateIndex into an offset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently I think you need to create a custom subclass. You'd need to override the `apply` and `onOffset` methods to take into account your holiday calendar.

We should add an optional holiday calendar parameter in the business-X frequencies eventually though. I made a github issue to keep track of it: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2301

Comment: I could see the functionality being more useful if it was done for all offsets rather than just business days.  There aren't many left but there are a few places that still consider Saturday a business day.  So something that excludes Sundays and given holidays would be necessary in that case.

Comment: @rhaskett I contributed some code to the issue on Github. Have a look if it meets your need.

Comment: Clever use of numpy.  I'll give it a shot when it hits production.  Thanks

Answer (score 9):

The CustomBusinessDay class has now been merged into the upcoming 0.12 release of Pandas where you will be able to do something like the following:

```
>>> from pandas.tseries.offsets import CustomBusinessDay
>>> 
>>> # As an interesting example, let's look at Egypt where
>>> # a Friday-Saturday weekend is observed.
>>> weekmask_egypt = 'Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu'
>>> 
>>> # They also observe International Workers' Day so let's
>>> # add that as a holiday for a couple of years
>>> holidays = ['2012-05-01', datetime(2013, 5, 1), np.datetime64('2014-05-01')]
>>> 
>>> bday_egypt = CustomBusinessDay(holidays=holidays, weekmask=weekmask_egypt)
>>> dt = datetime(2013, 4, 30)
>>> print dt + 2 * bday_egypt
2013-05-05 00:00:00
>>> 
>>> dts = date_range(dt, periods=5, freq=bday_egypt).to_series()
>>> print dts
2013-04-30   2013-04-30 00:00:00
2013-05-02   2013-05-02 00:00:00
2013-05-05   2013-05-05 00:00:00
2013-05-06   2013-05-06 00:00:00
2013-05-07   2013-05-07 00:00:00
Freq: C, dtype: datetime64[ns]
>>> 
>>> print Series(dts.weekday, dts).map(Series('Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun'.split()))
2013-04-30    Tue
2013-05-02    Thu
2013-05-05    Sun
2013-05-06    Mon
2013-05-07    Tue
dtype: object
```

HTH

Comment: Great. I've also been using it daily and have had no problems other than with plotting where the following workaround generally does the trick:  `custom_series.asfreq('B', method='pad').plot()`