# BDay offset in Pandas 1.0 return 2020-01-01 as a working day. Creating custom business class for USA efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, offset

I was surprised to see that Pandas offset BDay considers 2020-01-01 as a business working day.

Then I learned that I must use a CustomBusinessDay

[image]

Is there an efficient way to do that?  I am interested in the USA holidays during which the Markets are closed.

My original code was the following:

```
end_train = '2019-12-31'
end_train = pd.Timestamp(end_train)  # Converts the string to datetime
start_dev = end_train + BDay( 1)  # Looks forward 1 Business Day
start_dev = start_dev.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') # Converts the datetime to string

start_dev

'2020-01-01'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DateOffset in Pandas with a Holiday Calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13462802/dateoffset-in-pandas-with-a-holiday-calendar)

Comment: BDay is just weekday. You have to set holiday separately.